# Get url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the url with javascript. But I just need *http://www.mysite.com*, without any parameters behind it. any idea how to get that?

Comment: did you even bother to google that before asking?

Comment: Haters are hating again - damnit people... just be nice... You get points for asking/answering questions here.. Google doesn't give you points :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname
```